# Telegram WebHook - проблема с сертификатом

Tags: c#, azure, telegram-bot, x509certificate

- Приложение с вебхуком - из examples от библиотеки [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot/blob/master/README.md) с добавленной передачей сертификата из его же комментариев.
- Приложение развернуто на виртуалке в эйжуре
- Самоподписанный сертификат сгенерирован в точности с инструкциями с сайта телеграмма с реальным доменом xxxxxx.cloudapp.net и добавлен    в хранилище сертификатов виртуалки.
- Из него экспортирован PEM и его отправка добавлена в приложении.
- На виртуалке выполнены `netsh http add urlacl` и `netsh http add sslcert` по комментариям в коде
- в файрволе порты открыты, точки настроены
- `sslshopper` показывает, что отдается именно тот сертификат и проверки проходят, кроме предупреждения, что на такой сертификат могут ругаться некоторые браузеры
- НЕ РАБОТАЕТ - `getWebhookInfo` говорит

> ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Итогом, бот не отвечает в клиенте. Где здесь ошибка, что не так? всё взято в точности из примеров, что еще не так может быть с сертификатом?

Comment: Какие порты используете? `setWebHook` выполняли?

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo) и покажите нам результат.

Comment: Да, как-то странно связано было с портами. При замене на 443 всё взлетело.

Comment: `Ports currently supported for Webhooks: 443, 80, 88, 8443` это как бы из документации. А с какого поменяли?

Comment: Это из документации на API. 
А в текущей документации на SetWebHook в библиотеке обнаружилось _3. For the moment, the only supported port for Webhooks is 443. We may support additional ports later._

Поменял с 8443, который был в примере.

Comment: Добавьте в качестве ответа, думаю будет полезно